# Getting A Custom Random Number

Tags: batch-file, variables

So I a trying to use weapon damage, with a good prediction, but I don't know how I should replace this with variables...

```
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM%%% 100+1
```

I think it would be rewritten as this:

```
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM%%%Max%+%Min%
```

but I'm not sure... Thx Anyway :D

Comment: You're missing the second `%` between `%RANDOM%` and `%Max%`, but I see no reason why it wouldn't otherwise work. What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /A Max=100
set /A MIN=1
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM% %% %Max%+%Min%
```

Note that `SET /A RAND=%RANDOM% %% %Max%+%Min%` is equivalent to

```
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM% %% Max + Min
```

For an explanation, see [`SET A` examples](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions):

> `SET /A` will treat *any character string* in the expression as an
>   environment variable name. This allows you to do arithmetic with
>   environment variables without having to type any `%` signs to get the
>   values.

Above declaration is **not** valid for [volatile variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) so you need to use `%` percent signs as `%RANDOM%` (or `!` exclamation marks as `!RANDOM!` in necessity of using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)), see following examples (copy-paste from an open `cmd` window):

```
==> set /A RANDOM
0
==> set /A %RANDOM%
2651
```

Another examples (without a reasonable usage):

```
==> set /A CMDEXTVERSION
0
==> set /A %CMDEXTVERSION%
2
==> 2>NUL nonsens

==> set /A ERRORLEVEL
0
==> set /A %ERRORLEVEL%
9009
==>
```